# According to Reform Judaism, should rabbis be allowed to have non-Jewish spouses?

Tags: rabbis, reform-judaism, intermarriage

**According to Reform doctrine**, is it 1. *permissible* for rabbis to marry non-Jewish spouses, and 2. *advisable* for them to do so, considering that rabbis are generally seen as role-models of proper Jewish behavior?
In other words, *can* Reform rabbis have non-Jewish spouses, and if they can, *should* they?

Follow-up question: Should a synagogue or other religious institution hire a person for a rabbinical position who is married to a non-Jew?

---

I did some "research" on this topic, and found the following articles, which seem to just argue the sides without providing any real sources:

- ['Reform Magazine' article](http://reformjudaismmag.org/Articles/index.cfm?id=3202)
- ['Jewish Ideas Daily' article](http://www.jewishideasdaily.com/6350/features/faith-and-matrimony/)
- ['Times of Israel' article](http://blogs.timesofisrael.com/marriage-freedom-for-reform-rabbis/)

Comment: @IsaacMoses - I'm moving that information into a comment, since it does muddle the question a bit.  I'm looking for answers with sources, not just articles that recapitulate the debate.

Comment: http://forward.com/articles/176823/reform-rabbi-urges-hebrew-union-college-to-reconsi/

Comment: Seems the only questions about non-orthodox opinions are the upvoted are ones that fit into Orthodox stereotypes of non-orthodox problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current policy of Hebrew Union College - the primary Reform seminary in the United States (and thus I presume the world) - is not to admit rabbinic candidates with non-Jewish "significant others." This policy is currently being questioned in the blogosphere.

[From their website](http://huc.edu/admissions/rabbinical/apply-to-become-a-rabbi/):

> Current policy states that applicants who are married to or in committed relationships with non-Jews will not be considered for acceptance to this program.

Hebrew College of Boston (which, though not affiliated with the Reform movement, does graduate rabbis who lead Reform synagogues) has a similar requirement ([pdf](http://www.hebrewcollege.edu/sites/default/files/13-rab-application.pdf)).

I am not aware of any policy regarding what should happen to a rabbi if they were ordained by HUC and later married someone non-Jewish.

My understanding is that conceptually, Reform Judaism permits intermarriage, but a policy was developed that it would look wrong if a rabbi was not publicly committed enough to choose a Jewish spouse, or something to that effect.

Comment: According to a Reform rabbi I asked, the Reform governing rabbinical body (CCAR) does not have such a policy, and if a rabbi marries a non-Jew after they have been ordained, they are *not* kicked out or barred from being a rabbi.  But I was unable to find any official responsa or webpage with that policy.

Comment: I don't know if the CCAR has a position on this (I would think it would at least be strongly discouraged), but I can confirm the HUC policy from personal experience.  (This wouldn't be a barrier for me, but the question came up in a discussion with them about admission to their program.)

Comment: Hebrew College of Boston is not affiliated with the Reform or any other movement